# How to define a table in MySQL, so the time-stamp will be updated on insert?

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to define a new `MySQL` table, let's say table-1, with a timestamp column that will be initialized only on `INSERT` and not on UPDATE. How to do it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes

Answer (score 1):

you could use the deful value  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
create table table1 (

your_col  your_data_type , 
......
my_insert_date_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

);
```

and let the col my_insert_date_time  null  in insert